# Total count inside an if of while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to do the totalCount inside an if of a while loop
but so far are not successfull in doing so

How can i reach my goal with this code

```
    $rowCount = 1;
    while ($clientrows = $statement->fetch()) {
    // should return 1000 rows 
        if ($clientrows['company'] != $current_client) {
            echo $rowCount++;
            $rowCount++;
                    // return clientX (one time)        
        }
        if ($clientrows['time'] != NULL  ) {
                    // returns X rows of clientX(from the previews count 
                    // could be any number but lets say here it should be 100 rows


            echo $rowCount++;
            $rowCount++;
            // i need the total counts inside this IF($clientrows['time'] != NULL  )

        }
                    echo $rowCount++; // doesn't show anything 
        // create here the IF total count of previews IF function
        // if($totalCounts) {
        //      echo ' Do something here ';
        // }
    }
    echo $rowCount++; //shows the total rows of while loop while ($clientrows = $statement->fetch())
```

if i put the count++ right after the IF function it doesn't show anything if i do it at the end then it counts the total of everything

**EDIT**
Number of counts returns all the rows of my while loop of while ($clientrows = $statement->fetch() (that is about 1000) 
what i need to achieve is to get the total rows of this IF statment
if ($clientrows['time'] != NULL  ) { }
Which could be 100 or 101 or 200 of the 1000 rows

Help?

Comment: Are you sure the conditions are met?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you doing but you might need to delete the extra ++ on `echo $rowCount++;` since you're double counting

Comment: Chen the conditions are met, vlzvl i've just edited my question to clarify

Answer (score 1):

"++" is incrementation. It will add + 1 into your variable. It's equal as $a = $a + 1;

Intead of

```
echo $rowCount++;
$rowCount++;
```

write

```
echo $rowCount;
$rowCount++;
```

Edit.
I just read your comment in script

```
//shows the total rows of while loop while ($clientrows = $statement->fetch())
```

Can not you just simply use $statment->num_rows()?

Comment: Then `echo $rowCount++;` would be enough.

Comment: `echo $rowCount++;` will echo the `$rowCount` first and then increment it by one. `echo ++$rowCount;` will increment the `$rowCount` first and then echo it.

Comment: SoftGuide thanks for the answer but $statment->num_rows (i use pdo) so i made it $statement->rowCount() returns All the rows which is correct but i need to only get the total rows in my IF statement if ($clientrows['time'] != NULL  ) which could be any number i don't know from 100 rows to 200 or even 50

Answer (score 0):

When you do `echo $rowCount++;` you increment the `$rowCount` even if you only echo it.